# roKeyboardScreen Customization

Tags: roku

I could not find any docs on customization of `roKeyboardScreen` appearance, except for buttons (`ButtonNormalColor` & `ButtonHighlightColor`). I saw the ["roKeyboardScreen color" topic](http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=63561) but it has no any answers.

I have customized colors for breadcrumb text in all screens, and the `roKeyboardScreen`'s title color differs from it, causing bad (inconsistent) UI look & feel. Also, I'd be happy to know there are capabilities of customization of other `roKeyboardScreen` elements.

Any input would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this has been a long standing bug with the roKeyboardScreen.  As far as I'm aware, there is no way to change the color of the breadcrumb text on that screen.

There is, however, an undocumented theme attribute for changing the highlight color of the keys: `KeyboardKeyHighlightColor`